# canvasJS not working on mozilla and internet explorer

Tags: google-chrome, mozilla, canvasjs

my CanvasJS chart is only working on google chrome if someone has an idea I would be thankful.

They are live chart and the datas are pushed with json, on mozilla and internet explorer (9) i can only see the axes !

Difference between mozilla (latest version) and chrome :

[image]

Comment: You should specify the version of your tested browsers.

Comment: Mozilla latest version and internet explorer 9

Comment: No warnings or errors in the console?

Comment: Propriété « box-sizing » inconnue.  Déclaration abandonnée. -> Property box-sizing unknown. Declaration abort  They are a few error compare to chrome (none) and they come from bootstrap and this one : SyntaxError: Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead from jquery

Comment: Can you post the code or create a jsfiddle that can reproduce the issue?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/B6a3Aue7 here is the code

Comment: @user3241018 can you also post the json data as retruned by web services at "/ajax/data.php?pair=btc_usd" & "/ajax/historic.php?pair=btc_usd"

Comment: http://pastebin.com/EDEVvzU2 for data and http://pastebin.com/D0sPA8Bg for historic (sorry on pastebin its hard to read) (and by the way im using cakephp but im not a pro at all, i'm a student)

Answer (score 0):

CanvasJS Chart seems to be working fine across devices and browsers including Chrome v72.0.3626.121, Firefox v65.0.2, Opera v58.0.3135.79, Edge v44.17763.1.0, IE8+, Safari, Android Chrome, etc.

However this issue can be observed in few browsers when:

1. The x-value is date-time.
2. The value passed is not in one of the [Valid JavaScript Date formats](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp).

Browsers like Chrome, Firefox handles few invalid JS Date formats aswell, but browsers like IE doesn't. Because of this reason, chart seems to be incomplete / not rendered properly in IE.